Using one element to move/modify another on hover with CSS
I am trying to create a section of a page that has two columns and if you hover on the left side then both columns slide towards the middle (bringing the left column into a more prominent position), if you hover on the right side, both columns slide right (bringing the right column into a more prominent position).
I am able to achieve this for the left column, but not for the right, as it seems that the first div can move the second div, but the second div cannot move the first, so that when I hover on the right side, the right column slides towards the middle, but the left column stays put instead of sliding off to the side.


<style>
    @import url("https://use.typekit.net/poz1xqv.css");
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syne:wght@400..800&display=swap');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap')
    h2, h3 {
      .syne-font
    }
    p {
      .work-sans-light
    }
    .syne-font {
      font-family: "Syne", sans-serif;
      font-optical-sizing: auto;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-style: normal;
    }
    .work-sans-light {
      font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
      font-optical-sizing: auto;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-style: normal;
    }
    .work-sans-medium {
      font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
      font-optical-sizing: auto;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-style: normal;
    }
    .cta-button {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #000000;
      transition: 1s ease;
    }
    .cta-button:hover {
      background-color: #000000;
      color: #ffffff;
      transition: 1s ease;
    }
    .hidden-text {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: relative;
      opacity: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 1s ease;
    }
    .hidden-text:hover {
      opacity: 100;
    }
    .feature-image:hover ~ .hidden-text,
    .hidden-text:hover {
      opacity: 100;
    }
    .sliding-section {
      /* margin-left: -120px;
      margin-right: 120px; */
      position: relative;
      margin-left: -10%;
      margin-right: 10%;
      width: 120%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      transform: translateX(0);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .residential {
      position: relative;
      transform: translateX(0);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .residential:hover {
      transform: translateX(50px);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .residential:hover ~ .commercial{
      transform: translateX(50px);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .commercial {
      position: relative;
      transform: translateX(0);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .commercial:hover {
      transform: translateX(-50px);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
    .commercial:hover ~ .residential{
      transform: translateX(-50px);
      transition: ease 1s;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script>
    tailwind.config = {
      theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
            'TradeGothicNext': ['"Trade Gothic Next"', 'sans-serif']
          },
          fontFamily: {
            'Syne': ['"Syne"', 'sans-serif']
          },
          fontFamily: {
            'Work Sans': ['"Work Sans"', 'sans-serif']
          },
      colors: {
        greybg: '#CECCC4',
      }
          transitionDuration: {
            '300': '300ms',
          }
    }
      }
    }
  </script>


<div class="no-margin sliding-section w-screen z-3">
  <div class="w-full grid grid-cols-2 gap-10">
    <div class="residential feature-image">
      <img class="feature-image object-cover overflow-x-visible" src="https://danverstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/img4.jpg" alt="Residential" />
      <h3 class="feature-image text-right syne-font pt-4">Residential</h3>
      <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
        <div></div>
        <div class="hid-text2 hidden-text">
          <p class="hid-text2 text-right work-sans-light pt-4">See our wide variety of cabinet types and styles and how they can accommodate all of your outdoor kitchen needs</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="commercial">
      <img class="object-cover overflow-x-visible" src="https://danverstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/img5.jpg" alt="Commercial" />
      <h3 class="text-left syne-font pt-4">Hospitality & Multi-Family</h3>
      <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
        <div class="hid-text2 hidden-text"><p class="hid-text2 text-left work-sans-light pt-4">See our wide variety of cabinet types and styles and how they can accommodate all of your outdoor kitchen needs</p></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



This is a specific example that I'm working on, but there are other cases where I've been able to have two child elements within a parent where child #1 can modify child #2, but child #2 cannot modify child #1. How does the relationship between divs or elements work in this simple (Parent with child #1 and child #2) case?
Thanks in advance!

Could you put all your material into a code snippet so we know what is your current progress?

sorry but i only see single column here in your example, is that suppose to be the right or left column?

edited as a code snippet, thanks

You can utilize the :has() selector to check if the .commercial element is hovered then adjust the .residential element css
.residential:has(~.commercial:hover) {}


console.clear();
.sliding-section {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 120%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.residential {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.residential:hover {
  transform: translateX(50px);
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.residential:hover~.commercial {
  transform: translateX(50px);
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.commercial {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.commercial:hover {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  transition: ease 1s;
}

.residential:has(~.commercial:hover) {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  transition: ease 1s;
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="no-margin sliding-section w-screen">
  <div class="w-full grid grid-cols-2 gap-10">
    <div class="residential">
      <img class="object-cover overflow-x-visible" src="image.jpg" alt="Residential" />
      <h3 class=" text-right syne-font pt-4">Residential</h3>
      <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
        <div></div>
        <div class="">
          <p class="text-right work-sans-light pt-4">lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="commercial">
      <img class="object-cover overflow-x-visible" src="image.jpg" alt="Commercial" />
      <h3 class="text-left syne-font pt-4">Hospitality & Multi-Family</h3>
      <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
        <div class="">
          <p class="text-left work-sans-light pt-4">lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




this seems to work! Thank you. I'm still a bit confused on how the relationship works between those two elements, but this is a great workaround!

Glad it worked for you. Take a look at the MDN docs for :has() when you get a chance, as it has some very useful instances.
